# The Treeview is displaying stuff to the right of the of the Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter

There tree view is displaying to the right and when I need it to evenly display all the way through the window.
This is a CSV file reader and when the data is displayed all the data is pushed to the right and there is a big blank spot on the left side of the treeview and with the data being pushed all the way to the right the data is very hard to read because there is very limited visibility

```
import csv
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk, messagebox, simpledialog

class RoadSafetyApp:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Road Safety App")
        self.master.geometry("800x600")
        self.master.configure(bg="lightgray")
        self.data = []
        self.current_page = 0
        self.rows_per_page = 30

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master)
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.tree_frame = ttk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.tree_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.tree_frame)
        self.tree.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True)

        self.scrollbar_x = ttk.Scrollbar(self.tree_frame, orient="horizontal", command=self.tree.xview)
        self.scrollbar_x.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        self.tree.configure(xscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_x.set)

        self.scrollbar_y = ttk.Scrollbar(self.tree_frame, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
        self.scrollbar_y.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_y.set)

        self.edit_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Admin Edit", command=self.admin_edit, bg='black', fg="white", relief='groove', pady='10', padx='10')
        self.edit_button.pack(side="left")

        self.load_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Load CSV", command=self.load_data, bg='black', fg="white", relief='groove', pady='10', padx='100')
        self.load_button.pack(side="left")

        self.search_entry = tk.Entry(self.master, bg='white', fg="black", relief='groove', width=20)
        self.search_entry.pack(side="left", pady='10', padx='10')

        self.column_dropdown = ttk.Combobox(self.master, values=[], state="readonly", width=15)
        self.column_dropdown.pack(side="left", pady='10', padx='10')

        self.search_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Search", command=self.search_data, bg='black', fg="white", relief='groove', pady='10', padx='100')
        self.search_button.pack(side="left")

        self.next_page_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Scroll Down", command=self.next_page, bg='black', fg="white", relief='groove', pady='10', padx='100')
        self.next_page_button.pack(side="right")

        self.help_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Help", command=self.show_help, bg='black', fg='white', relief='groove', pady='10', padx='10')
        self.help_button.pack(side="right")

        self.row_data_frame = tk.Frame(self.master, bg="lightgray", pady='10')
        self.row_data_frame.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

        self.tree.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.show_row_data)
    def show_help(self):
        help_text= """
Welcome to Queensland Crashes!
Instructions:
1.Load the car crash CSV that you want to read about
2.Use the seach button to find specific data
3.Use the scroll down button to scroll down if more rows are avaiable

FOR ADMIN -
1.Press on Admin
2.Input password - (Password1)
3.Edit Data
"""
        messagebox.showinfo("Help", help_text)
    def admin_edit(self):
        password = simpledialog.askstring("Password", "Enter the password:", show='*')
        if password == "Password1":
            self.edit_data_window()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Authentication Error", "Invalid password!")

    def edit_data_window(self):
        if not self.data:
            messagebox.showwarning("No Data", "Load a CSV file first.")
            return

        edit_window = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        edit_window.title("Edit Data")

        scrollbar_y_edit = tk.Scrollbar(edit_window, orient="vertical")
        scrollbar_y_edit.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        scrollbar_x_edit = tk.Scrollbar(edit_window, orient="horizontal")
        scrollbar_x_edit.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

        edit_canvas = tk.Canvas(edit_window, yscrollcommand=scrollbar_y_edit.set, xscrollcommand=scrollbar_x_edit.set)
        edit_canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        edit_frame = tk.Frame(edit_canvas, bg="lightgray")
        edit_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=edit_frame, anchor="nw")

        scrollbar_y_edit.config(command=edit_canvas.yview)
        scrollbar_x_edit.config(command=edit_canvas.xview)

        columns = list(self.data[0].keys())

        entry_labels = []
        entry_values = []

        for i, col in enumerate(columns):
            tk.Label(edit_frame, text=f"{col}:", bg="lightgray").grid(row=i, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="w")
            entry = tk.Entry(edit_frame, bg='white', fg="black", relief='groove', width=20)
            entry.grid(row=i, column=1, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="w")
            entry_labels.append(col)
            entry_values.append(entry)

        save_button = tk.Button(edit_frame, text="Save Data", command=lambda: self.save_edited_data(entry_labels, entry_values, edit_window), bg='black', fg="white", relief='groove', pady='10', padx='10')
        save_button.grid(row=len(columns), column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

        edit_frame.update_idletasks()
        edit_canvas.config(scrollregion=edit_canvas.bbox("all"))
        edit_canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: edit_canvas.configure(scrollregion=edit_canvas.bbox("all")))

    def save_edited_data(self, entry_labels, entry_values, edit_window):
        # Modify this function to save the entered data to the CSV file
        # You can access the entered values using entry_values[i].get()
        # and the corresponding column name using entry_labels[i]
        # Once saved, you can update the Treeview to reflect the changes
        # Example: self.tree.item(item_id, values=new_values)
        messagebox.showinfo("Save", "Data saved successfully!")
        edit_window.destroy()

    def load_csv(self, file_path):
        rows = []
        with open(file_path, 'r') as csvfile:
            csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in csvreader:
                rows.append(row)
        return rows

    def load_data(self):
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("CSV files", "*.csv")])
        if file_path:
            self.data = self.load_csv(file_path)
            if self.data:
                self.display_data()

    def display_data(self):
        self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())

        if not self.data:
            print("No data to display")
            return

        columns = list(self.data[0].keys())
        self.tree["columns"] = columns

        for col in columns:
            self.tree.heading(col, text=col, anchor='center')
            self.tree.column(col, width=150, anchor='center')  # Increased column width for better spacing

        self.column_dropdown["values"] = columns
        self.column_dropdown.set(columns[0])

        start_idx = self.current_page * self.rows_per_page
        end_idx = start_idx + self.rows_per_page
        current_page_data = self.data[start_idx:end_idx]

        for i, row in enumerate(current_page_data):
            values = [row.get(col, "") for col in columns]
            self.tree.insert("", "end", values=values)

        self.canvas.update_idletasks()
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def next_page(self):
        total_pages = len(self.data) // self.rows_per_page + 1
        if self.current_page < total_pages - 1:
            self.current_page += 1
            self.display_data()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Page Errors", "There is nothing else to scroll down to!")

    def search_data(self):
        query = self.search_entry.get().lower()
        selected_column = self.column_dropdown.get()
        result_rows = [row for row in self.data if query in str(row.get(selected_column, "")).lower()]
        self.display_search_results(result_rows)

    def display_search_results(self, result_rows):
        self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())

        columns = list(self.data[0].keys())
        self.tree["columns"] = columns

        for col in columns:
            self.tree.heading(col, text=col, anchor='center')
            self.tree.column(col, width=150, anchor='center')

        for i, row in enumerate(result_rows):
            values = [row.get(col, "") for col in columns]
            self.tree.insert("", "end", values=values)

        self.canvas.update_idletasks()
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def show_row_data(self, event):
        selected_item = self.tree.selection()
        if selected_item:
            row_id = self.tree.identify_row(event.y)
            if row_id:
                row_index = int(row_id[1:]) - 1  # Extract the row index from the row ID
                row_data = self.data[row_index]
                self.display_row_data(row_data)

    def display_row_data(self, row_data):
        row_data_window = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        row_data_window.title("Row Data")

        row_count = 0
        for key, value in row_data.items():
            label = tk.Label(row_data_window, text=f"{key}: {value}", bg="lightgray", fg="black", padx=10, pady=5)
            label.grid(row=row_count // 4, column=row_count % 4, sticky="w")
            row_count += 1


# Main execution
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.configure(bg="lightgray")
    app = RoadSafetyApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I need the tree view to still be readable but also for it not to be pushed all the way to the right of the window.

Answer (score 0):

That space to the left is column #0 which contains the "tree" part of the tree. If you don't want to see it you can do `self.tree.configure(show="headings")`. This tells the treeview to show the heading row and not the tree column.

Alternatively, you can set a size for this column and configure it to not expand to fill extra space. For example, `self.tree.column("#0", width=10, stretch=False)` will give you a 10 pixel wide column.